# Song about stars, long piano intro, rap

Tags: identify-this-song, rap, piano

There was a song I was obsessed with in college (2009/2010) that I can’t remember for the life of me and it’s driving me insane! It may have come out around that year or a bit earlier. Definitely a 2000’s song.

From what I remember it had a long piano intro and I think maybe a small rap segment near the end. The piano was beautiful!

It wasn’t a well known band, and I feel like the title had something to do with stars. Like falling stars or dark stars and had a number as well.

This is all I can remember. I just know that I loved it and that it didn’t really make sense lyrically. It felt like it would fit into the alternative/emo/indie genre.

Comment: Hi Hannah. Identification questions need more details to be answerable... I suggest you to read [What should I do to improve my identification question?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-i-do-to-improve-my-identification-question) will give you some ideas of details that you should add.

Comment: When were you in college?  Was the song new at that time?  If not, when do you think the song came out?

Comment: I was in college in 2009/2010. It may have been a few years older.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest [B.o.B' *Airplanes* ft. Hayley Williams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn6-c223DUU).

- It has a piano intro.
- There are several rap segments by the rapper B.o.B.
- The chorus says :

  > Can we pretend that airplanes in the night sky are like **shootin' stars**

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not it. Though it was around that same time that I listened to this! It wasn’t popular or on the radio like that was.